# sending specific data into a collection partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I have a `User` class with a `has_many :messages` and a `Message` class which `belongs_to :user`.  In the `Message` controller's show action has the corresponding view:

```
<% if @messages.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/message', collection: @messages %>
  </ol>
<% end %>
```

And the `shared/_message.html.erb` template looks like this:

```
<li id="<%= message.id %>">
  <span class="content"><%= message.body %></span>
  <% user_id = message.from %>
  <% user = User.find(user_id) %>
  From: <%= user.name %>
</li>
```

I feel like the following two lines should be done in the `Messages` controller from what I read in tutorials on Rails:

```
<% user_id = message.from %>
<% user = User.find(user_id) %>
```

But how would I pass each message's corresponding `from` value (which stores user.id) into the partial?

thanks,
mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far i have understood that you have a `from` column in your `messages` table which stores the `user_id`. So if you call `message.from` it returns the `user_id`. Then you can do the following

```
class Message < AR::Base
     belongs_to :user, :foreign_key=>'from' 
end
```

In your controller

```
@messages = Message.all.includes(:user)
#It will load messages and will associated users eager loaded.
```

Now in your view you can call `message.user.name` to get the user's name directly. You dont need these following two lines in your view at all

<strike><% user_id = message.from %>

<% user = User.find(user_id) %></strike>

Let me know if ive missed anything.

---

#### UPDATE:

Here is what Ive tried with

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :age, :name
    has_many :sent_messages,    :class_name=>'Message', :foreign_key => 'from'
    has_many :received_messages,:class_name=>'Message', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
#Contains Data:
#<User id: 1, name: "p1", age: 27, ... ...>, 
#<User id: 2, name: "p2", age: 25, ... ...
```

**Message Model**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :body, :sender, :title, :receipent
    belongs_to :sender,     :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'from'
    belongs_to :receipent,  :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
```

Now say `p1` is sending a message to `p2`

```
p1.sent_messages.create(title: "test title", body: "test body", receipent: p2)
#Result:
#<Message id: 1, title: "test title", body: "test body", user_id: 2, from: 1 ... ... >
```

Now for a `message`, you can get both `sender` and `receipent` directly like

```
@messages = Message.includes(:sender, :receipent) # You can load only sender or only receipent

#In View
message.sender.name 
#OR
message.receipent.name
```

Comment: My messages table has both a `user_id` and a `from` field.  I need both because `user_id` holds the id of the user who's the message recipient while the `from` field holds the user id of the sender.

I set it like so:
`user.messages.create(body: content, from: current_user.id)`

Comment: I thought foreign keys go only with the `belongs_to` method?

Comment: If you provide foreign keys with `belongs_to`, it assumes the column in same table. But if you provide with `has_many` then it assumes in the related table. Ultimately both are same place :) This is because you may need to define relationship anywhere. Like in my example, I used all 4 possible relationships. You can remove if you dont need anyone.